# Husband's earning in the USA and mine from India | How to report in joint USA tax return

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, joint-tax-return

Please do not confuse it with [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/88682/mutual-fund-investments-in-india-to-be-reported-in-usa-whats-the-limit-of-amou) question here. It is about a different source of income and a different filling status.

**Context**:
I came to the USA via F2 (student visa) in September 2021 after getting married. My husband’s status is resident alien and he has an SSN. Additionally, he was on an F1 visa for the entire 2021. We have decided to file a joint income tax return for the first time in 2021. I have income in India via salary and consultancy and no income in the USA. My husband's complete income is from the USA.

**Questions**:

1. What is the limit above which I will have to disclose my income from India in our US income tax return?
2. What is the upper limit of income from India above which it will be taxable in the USA? (Already paying tax in India)

Please feel free to ask if the situation is not clear.

Comment: when you say "we have filed", do you mean "we decided to file"? Because these questions should be asked *before* filing a return...

Comment: Highly suggest you consider seeking professional guidance if the pending tax amounts are substantial; there could be valuable tax planning that you might not find yourself, or steps to ensure proper compliance.

Comment: You can check the IRS guidance on this situation here: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-alien-figuring-your-tax

Comment: "My husband’s status is resident alien" Are you sure about that? When did he come on F1? If he came in 2017 or later, and he was never in F or J status before 2017, he was almost certainly a nonresident alien for all of 2021.

Comment: @littleadv, thanks for pointing, I have updated the "decided to file part".

Comment: @user102008 Yes, we are sure he is a resident alien, no doubts about that (we know about the substantial presence test.).

Comment: @ChotuMotu: And you are aware that days of presence as a student are not counted in the Substantial Presence Test for the first 5 calendar years?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the limit above which I will have to disclose my income from India in our US income tax return?

You have to disclose all of it, since the US is taxing worldwide income and you're filing as residents for the whole year.

> What is the upper limit of income from India above which it will be taxable in the USA? (Already paying tax in India)

Again, no upper limit just as no lower limit. You can use [Foreign Tax Credit](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc856) (form 1116) to account for your taxes paid in India. You may be eligible for [Foreign Earned Income Exclusion](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion), check the eligibility rules.

---

Following up on the comments - you wouldn't be able to file as a full-year resident unless you filed under MFJ status ("Married Filing Jointly"). However, in this situation you need to think whether you actually **want** to file as a full-year resident. What was alluded to in the comments was that filing MFS ("Married Filing Separately") with separate returns for each of you and a split-year return ([dual-status return](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxation-of-dual-status-aliens)) or non-resident return for you may be beneficial.

Agree with the advice that you should probably talk to a professional (CPA/EA licensed in your State).

Comment: Are you sure about this? Seems to assume OP files "married filing jointly"; the old accounting joke that MFS stands for "married filing stupid" doesn't apply here; it is quite possible that Married Filing Separate leads to preferential tax outcome, precisely because OP's income pre-September from India might not need to be reported on US taxes.

Comment: (I know the OP states they are "filing jointly for the first time", but I take that as colloquially meaning "filing for the first time after being marred", not shorthand for "selecting Married Filing Jointly on our returns").

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I'm not assuming, that's what the OP says.

Comment: I doubt the OP is aware of the intricacies of filing as MFJ vs MFS, it seems to me to be non-technical use of the term 'jointly'.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon she wouldn't be able to file as a full year resident unless they actually filed MFJ.

Comment: But why would she care about filing as full year resident? The point I am raising is that the option to file as MFS is one that should be considered - may or may not lead to preferential tax outcomes, but it is something that needs to be calculated to know.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon not disagreeing. I answered the question asked, but I edited my answer to address your concern.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: "it is quite possible that Married Filing Separate leads to preferential tax outcome, precisely because OP's income pre-September from India might not need to be reported on US taxes" I don't think that that's likely. Needing to report income on US taxes doesn't mean needing to pay taxes on that income. She can almost certainly use the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion on the 12-month period before she came to the US, to exclude the US tax from her income from India, and it is likely that her income from India is all earned income and is under the FEIE limit.

Comment: @littleadv: "filing MFS ("Married Filing Separately") with separate returns for each of you and a split-year return (dual-status return) for you" If they file as MFS the OP would be a nonresident alien for the whole year, not dual-status.

Comment: @user102008 that kindof depends on how the resident spouse is resident, not sure if F2 can be excluded from substantial presence if F1 cannot be. Anyway, talking to a pro is the way. They seem to specifically wanting to be considered residents, and maybe there's a non-tax related reason for that

Comment: @littleadv: Reading Publication 519 and the statute, the 5-year limit on being an exempt individual as a student is per individual

Comment: @user102008 yes, but it's not statutory (they can technically be treated as residents, just being on F status doesn't preclude), and there also may be treaty benefits involved etc, it's not necessarily black and white and there may be considerations we don't know of. One I can think of is trying to get some refundable credits.

Comment: @user102008 BTW I already commented on it here: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/149752/2998

Comment: @littleadv: It is statutory. 26 USC 7701(b)(1)(A) defines resident alien as any alien passing Green Card Test, Substantial Presence Test, or uses First-Year Choice. 26 USC 7701(b)(3)(D)(i) excludes days as exempt individual from SPT. 26 USC 7701(b)(5)(A)(iii) includes "students" as exempt individuals, where "student" is defined in 26 USC 7701(b)(5)(D) to include anyone in F status who complies with that status. 26 USC 7701(b)(5)(E)(ii) provides the 5-year limit. Tax treaties can break ties when one is a resident of 2 countries, but I don't think any tax treaty makes a nonresident a resident.

Comment: @littleadv: You commented on whether the husband is a resident, which is a good point since if they are both nonresidents, they cannot do MFJ. However, I was commented on the fact that if they do MFS, the wife must be a nonresident alien for the whole year, if she hadn't been to the US before, so she wouldn't be dual-status.